# query parameter books accepts an array of enum values. Is there a way I can give 400 bad request if a particular combination of values is received?

Tags: api, rest, dataweave, mulesoft, raml

```
books?:
      type: array
      items:
        enum: [a,b,c,d]
```

Let's say I want to give a bad request whenever b,c come together. Eg:

[a,b,c,d] -> invalid request

[a,b,c] -> invalid request

[b,c] -> invalid

In short, if a request has both b & c together, can 400 be displayed using RAML ?

Answer (score 2):

You can declare different types of valid combinations and then use them as possible input types.

Something like:

```yaml
types:
  validCombinationA: 
    type: array
    items:
      enum:
        - a
        - b
        - d

  validCombinationB: 
    type: array
    items:
      enum:
        - a
        - c
        - d
```

And then:

```yaml
books?:
  type: validCombinationA | validCombinationB
```

That way is going to fail whenever you use an invalid combination.
If the valid combinations are static and the probability of new future values is small, then it's not a big deal using this approach but if that's not the case, you will need to create X number of types for each valid combination.

Maybe it worths a thought of consideration look for other possibilities for your use case (eg: with OAS that can be done with the usage of elements such as `oneOf`, `anyOf`, `allOf`, `not`).

If the validation is quite simple, then I'd prefer to do it that way instead of using the [Validation Module](https://docs.mulesoft.com/validation-connector/1.4/) or something else inside a flow given that probably has an impact on performance (do some quick tests to verify it).

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. RAML is not expected to be used to define data validation. RAML only define validations of types and the structure of requests. You need to implement that kind of rule in the implementation of the API. In this particular case it seems that you are using Mule to implement the API. Inside the Mule application project you need to perform the validation in the flows.